# Django search form returning entire model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a simple search form for class based views with Django. Everything seems to work, except the search result returns the entire model, so obviously the search/filter isn't working. I cannot figure out why after reading a bunch of tutorials and questions here.

`models.py`:

```
class surveys(models.Model):
    FAN = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.FAN

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('survey-detail', args=[str(self.FAN)])
```

`views.py`:

```
class Search(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'datalibrary/search.html'
    model = surveys

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            name = self.kwargs['name']
        except:
            name = ''
        if (name != ''):
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(FAN__icontains == name)
        else:
            object_list = ''
        return object_list

class SearchResults(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'datalibrary/search_results.html'
    model = surveys
```

`search.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="get" action="/results/" class="navbar-form pull-right">
        <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" >
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

`search_results.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %} 
    {{ object_list }}
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns +=[
    path('search/', views.Search.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('results/', views.SearchResults.as_view(), name='search-results'),
]
```

Any idea why `object_list` returns all the values in the model rather filtering based on the input, even when there's no input?

Comment: You didn't post your urls.py but obviously your form is posting to the `SearchResults` view, not to the `Search` view. Hint: you don't need two distinct views here

Comment: Updated with my `urls.py`. Tried in a single view another answer showed, but not having any luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have name = self.kwargs['name'], which does not getting any 'name', for search a better way is to take the input name as query and show the results.

```
class Search(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'datalibrary/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(Search, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('search') #your input name is 'search'

        if query:
           object_list = surveys.objects.filter(FAN__icontains=query) #or FAN__contains
           result = object_list
        else:
           result = None    # When no result found

        return result
```

In Html,

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

 {% block content %}
  <form method="get" action="/results/" class="navbar-form pull-right">
     <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="search" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" >
  </form>



  {% for result in all_search_results %}
       {{result.add_according_to_the_model}}
  {% empty %}
        <p> No Results <p>
  {% endfor %}

   {% endblock %}
```

You can show search results in the same page. However if it is required for you then you can have different html.

Comment: Thanks for showing that method. Unfortunately when I tried it I got a 404 error with the message `The current path, results/, didn't match any of these.` Any idea what that could be? I updated my question with my original `urls.py`.

Comment: Because it is `path('results/', views.SearchResults.as_view(), name='search-results'),` not used for anything. In my answer, all search result is in the same search.html using class `Search`. So You can remove `class SearchResult` and path to SearchResult view that is giving you error.

Comment: I thought I had tried that and got a similar error. I just tried changing `action="/results/"` to 'action="/datalibrary/search/"` and that worked! Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called `self.kwargs['name']`, but your view won't have any such item.

Firstly, the name of the search input in your HTML is `search`, not `name`.

And secondly, `self.kwargs` is for elements that are captured from the URL; but this is sent as a GET form, so you should get it from the querystring: `self.request.GET['search']`.

Putting it together, in a slightly more idiomatic way:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    name = self.kwargs.get('name')
    object_list = self.model.objects.all()
    if name:
        object_list = object_list.filter(FAN__icontains == name)
    return object_list
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a few questions I had. I tried your correction, but it's still returning the same result.

Comment: Wait, what is that separate SearchResults view? Is your results URL pointing directly at that? If so then you need to l the get_queryset method *there*, not on the Search view.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I tried adding the get_queryset method to SearchResults view, but I'm getting a 404 error with message `The current path, results/, didn't match any of these.`